# AFNetworking not getting proper response

Tags: ios, rest, afnetworking

I'm trying to use AFNetworking to call a Rest API but I'm not getting the proper response string. This is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.ez-point.com/api/v1/ezpoints"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"testing");
            NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseData);

        }
            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                NSLog(@"%@", @"Error");
        }];

    [operation start];
```

but I'm getting this as print out:

```
2013-10-29 08:31:08.175 EZ-POINT[4004:c07] testing
2013-10-29 08:31:08.175 EZ-POINT[4004:c07] (null)
```

As you can see, it is returning null, I was expecting this:

```
{"status": "user_invalid", "data": "", "token": "", "errors": ["user not found"], "user_id": ""}
```

Comment: try to log the `JSON`param, that's being returned in completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more accustomed to this way of setting up the request:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.ez-point.com/api/v1/ezpoints"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"testing");
        NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseData);

    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Error");
    }];

[operation start];
```

Comment: yeah, it works, do you know how to pass the authorization token??

Comment: Sorry, I have not been working much with tokens.  We use other methods for our authorization.  Perhaps an additional questions would garner help from another person on here.

Comment: Oh wait-... [request setValue: @"X-USER-TOKEN"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"< clientToken >"];  or in the case of facebook:  [request setValue: @"token" forHttpHeaderField:@"access_token"];

Comment: forHTTPHeaderField doesn't exist

Comment: No it does exist for NSMutableURLRequest